# Writing text files fails on deployment

Tags: vb.net

I have a fairly elaborate VB.NET solution that I've been developing for a number of years. I rather suddenly ran into a problem that I've been spending too much time spinning my wheels on. I need help.

One function of the solution is to write a simple text file to a specified location. This has been working without a problem until very recently (2 or 3 weeks?) and the details are weird. The symptoms are these:

When writing to the "normal" location on a server:

1. Running export from an older (installed) version of the program works fine.
2. Running export while debugging within Visual Studio works fine.
3. Running export from a recently compiled version of the exe in either the Debug or Release folder results in one of two failures:
   a) The file does not close, requiring closing the file manually.
   b) There is an unauthorized access error, the file cannot be written at all, is set to "no access" and must be closed manually.
   c) These failures occur when running as administrator and/or to my own share on the server.
4. Running an older version of the exe from either folder works.

If the write location is changed to the local machine it works fine in all instances.

Some notes about my environment:

1. I'm still using VS2010 because I'm using a SQLCE database.
2. Using .Net Framework 4.0

I would like to deploy the more recent version of the program but can't really do so until I get this figured out.

I don't know much about the deeper aspects of compilation but it's obvious that something is going on there and whatever changed, changed recently. Any ideas? Anyone? Why would it work while "debugging" but not when "deployed?" Could a recent update of .Net broken something?

Things I've tried:

1. Using various methods of writing (OpenFile, StreamWriter).
2. Assuring that the File/Writer is closed.
3. Rebuild.
4. Reconstruct the entire program by copying and "adding" each project to a new project folder.
5. Rebuild using VS 2022.
6. sfc /scannow

Comment: An added note: I have not made any changes to the export routine.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I got a hint from somewhere on stackoverflow. I disabled AV software  and the file(s) close properly. Enabled AV software and files would not close. Disabled again, files close.

There must have been a recent update on the AV software. Now all I have to do is convince AV software that my program is not evil.

Comment: Can u find and share the original stackoverflow post helped u

Comment: @yannickingenierie I guess it wasn't stackoverflow. Codeproject maybe   https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/147196/C-ASP-NET-StreamWriter-not-properly-releasing-file

Comment: ok always good to give your source. :-) Perhaps next time just say antivirus without writing the one u use (hide some important security informations)